# Apache htaccess Rewrite for File and Folder That Share the Same Name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following API endpoints:

```
/api/project
/api/project/start
/api/project/end
```

These endpoints are supported by a file structure that looks like:

```
/api/project.php
/api/project/start.php
/api/project/end.php
```

I am currently using `.htaccess` to make the `.php` extension optional to the API user.

I noticed that if I hit `/api/project` without the `.php` extension, I get taken to the `project` folder on Apache instead of the `project.php` file.

Is there anyway to account for this in the `.htaccess` file or through a different method?

My current `.htaccess` rewrite rules

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I get taken to the project folder on Apache instead". Do you get a list of files in that folder?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes, it shows the directory list

Comment: `Option -Indexes` should prevent displaying list of files

Comment: This is generated by mod_autoindex. I believe you can turn that of with `Options -Indexes`.

Comment: @Lashane @Sumurai8 Is this an option in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @LloydBanks usually this option in .htaccess, but you can place it in httpd.conf too

Comment: You can also add rewrite condintions based on whether a `REQUEST_FILENAME` is a file, dir, or symlink. I would think performing some of these checks might come into play here.

Comment: You should post your current .htaccess file / rewrite rules.

Comment: Looking at your current rewrite rules, they should be correct. Just add `Options -Indexes` as suggested.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That prevents the directory listing from being displayed, but I still need to append `.php` to the end of the API endpoint

Comment: @LloydBanks Your current RewriteRule looks like it would already accomplish that. It should apply regardless of whether the directory actually exists

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Apache is still sending the requests to the directory

Comment: @LloydBanks Add a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` before the other 2 conditions - I would expect that to solve it, but am not certain it won't break other normal directories which should _not_ be written to .php.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Still no dice.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @LloydBanks Not really - at this point you would need to crank up `RewriteLog` and examine what it's doing. Make sure you test it in a private browsing window to get around caching issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding `DirectorySlash Off` to my `.htaccess` file.

Apache automatically adds a trailing slash to the end of URLs if a directory by that name exists.

Once you update your `.htaccess` file and restart your server, you need to clear your browser cache (since most browsers will add the trailing slash to the end of your request if previous requests were automatically redirected).